# Can a C++ reference parameter have the same name as the argument?

Tags: c++, reference

I'm rusty on references, but I know they are just another name for a variable. Going off that, what if you have a reference that's the same name? Why would it work/not work?

For example:

```
foo(int &a) {
   printf(a);
}
main() {
   int a;
   foo(a);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, in this case, `printf(a)` where `a` is an `int` shouldn't work at all, regardless of name.

Comment: I think you also need a better understanding scoping rules.  If the function foo parameter was just an `int a`, not `int &a`, that would also "work" with the same name as the passed in parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Why would it work/not work?"*

In terms of name of your argument: **Yes**, it will work. The `a` in main is a local variable, the identifier `a`, which refers to this variable is valid only within the same scope. In `foo`, there's an argument `a`, but this `a` is different identifier than the first one.

---

PS: I assume that this:

```
printf(a);
```

was meant to be:

```
printf("%d", a);
```

Comment: It is helpful to distinguish between a variable and references to it. A variable is a set of memory locations interpreted in a particular way (its type). It may be referred to in several different ways. For example `int a;` creates bytes for storing a number and arranges for it to be named `a`. Similarly, `int b[10];` creates 10 variables; the third one may be named `b[2]`. A reference variable `int &r=b[2];` creates a variable and arranges for uses of it to refer to another variable. Naming `r` causes the variable _it_ _points_ _to_, to be named; the third `b` variable in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work.. `int &a` is local variable of function which will recieve just reference passed to it and it's scope is limited to this function only whereas `a` in Main function has scope within main function.